# Can function calls in other contracts change states?

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation

In Solidity, is it possible to change states via function calls in other contracts?

For example, let's consider the code below, where we have three assumptions:

1. The function `test2` is defined in the contract `C2`.
2. The contract object `c2` of the type `C2` is created at somewhere within `C1`.
3. We deployed `C1` as a root contract.

Then, is it possible for the function call statement `c2.test2()` to change the values of variables in `C1` (e.g., x1, x2, x3, etc)?

```
Contract C1 {
  uint x1;
  uint x2;
  uint x3;

  ...

  function test1 () public{
     /* can c2.test2() change the values of variables */
     /*   within C1? (e.g., x1,x2,x3, etc) */
     c2.test2 (); 
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A contract's state variables can only be changed by that contract. But of course the contract can expose a method that other contracts can call, e.g.:

```
contract C1 {
    uint256 foo;
    function setFoo(uint256 value) external {
        foo = value;
    }
}
```

Now anyone (and any contract) can call `setFoo` to change the value of `C1`'s `foo` state variable.